# Convert multiple rows of text into a Single row using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["Hi how are you","I am fine","I love you","I hate you"]})
```

I would like to convert all these individual rows into a single row

I tried the below but it is incorrect and doesn't work

```
df['text'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try via `agg()`,`to_frame()` and `reset_index()`:

```
out=(df.agg(' '.join)
        .to_frame('text')
        .reset_index(drop=True))
```

output of out:

```
    text
0   Hi how are you I am fine I love you I hate you
```

Comment: thanks, may I know what does `1` mean? upvoted

Comment: You can just `df.agg(' '.join).to_frame('text')`.

Comment: @TheGreat updated answer....kindly have a look **:)** there 1 was `axis=1`